# How can i only run a batch file without using .sln/.proj file from tfs build server?

Tags: tfs

i have a nant script working for my project which one i try to use as a build script in tfs.
Is it possible?? if it is possible then how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) that includes both "InvokePowerShellCommand" and "InvokeRemoteStropt" and I am sure there is a couple I missed..